# Is it possible to implement a custom cell renderer for Google Sheets?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-api

Is it possible to implement a custom cell renderer for Google Sheets?

For example I want to show "rich" links (override link with icon and document title) if I referenced some Google Doc document in a cell?

I've investigated their API reference and don't see any reference, but I feel that I've missed something.

Answer (score 0):

Open the document you want to link to. Then open your spreadsheet and select the cell you want the link to appear in. Then from the spreadsheet menu, select link. In the popup window put the name you want for the link (rich) then copy the url from the document into link. That should do it.

Comment: Ed, thanks for suggestion! It works, but I'm looking for a way to automate it. Also I want it to be a kind of live reference - if a state or tags or target document will change, it should be automatically updated in my sheet.